# How do i get the upper (and lower) limits of an axis in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How do I find the minimum and maximum of the axis in a MATLAB plot?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's how you can do it for the current axes (i.e. [`gca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html)):

```
xLimits = get(gca,'XLim');  % Get the range of the x axis
yLimits = get(gca,'YLim');  % Get the range of the y axis
zLimits = get(gca,'ZLim');  % Get the range of the z axis
```

Each variable above will be a 1-by-2 array containing the minimum and maximum values for the respective axis. You can check [the documentation on axes properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-XLim) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you mind going the properties way use

`xlim` `ylim` or `zlim` to retrieve min and max value or

`xlim([minValue maxValue])` to set the limits.

See [set or query axis limits](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ylim.html) for additional parameters.