# Unable to set the Lower limit of x-axis in Matlab Histogram

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have to plot a histogram of some data, I have 1000 values the cast majority of which are zero. The remaining values are all positive.

I have several sets of data most of which when I plot the data I get a graph with a sharp peak at zero and some other values dotted around. This is correct as shown below:
[image]

However occasionally the x-axis starts off negative (despite there being no negative values present). As shown below

[image]

I only want the lower x-limit to change I still want the upper x-limit and both y-limits to be automatic.

Based on this answer here:

[How do i get the upper (and lower) limits of an axis in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965344/how-do-i-get-the-upper-and-lower-limits-of-an-axis-in-matlab)

I tried:

```
set(gca, 'Xlim', ([0 Inf]));
```

But this hasn't changed anything?

Answer (score 2):

> I only want the lower x-limit to change I still want the upper x-limit and both y-limits to be automatic.

Get the current x-limit and then just change the lower limit:

```
histogram(randi(10,100,1)-1);
xLimits = get(gca,'XLim');
set(gca, 'Xlim', ([0 xLimits(2)]));
```

Comment: I tried the code above but the graph still displays the negative values?

Comment: @Bazman it works for me on MATLAB R2015a; please post a [MCVE] which exhibits this problem

Comment: I'd have to post the data and there are 1000 data points? Is this what you want?